# OMF - video sync query

Tags: post-production

OMF query,
I received an OMF, quicktime video file and audio guide track.
The omf and the guide track have a 2pop.
When I imported in the video file and the guidetrack I noticed that the one frame of flash on the video file happens 2 frames before the guide track 2 pop.
Should I sync my omf 2pop to the video flash or try sync to the guide track 2 pop.
Secondly what might cause the video editor to have a 2 frame difference between the video and guide track?
He has gone on holidays so I can’t ask them for a few days.
Using PAL standard I notice that the frame rate I was given was 29.97. When I change to this in setup it corrects by a part of a frame but I am still 2 frames out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep the omf two pop and audio where it is and shift the video two frames to it. That way you do not create any sync issue. If he gets a file back that is off, then it's on him to figure out what he did because you moved nothing and simply worked off the omf given. Your omf should be accurate to his video timeline. It's more likely there is an issue with either the quicktime or guide track. When delivering the mix, bring the discrepancy to his attention so that he is aware to check sync and indicate to him that you simply left the omf timeline alone not to complicate matters.